# ¿Cómo evaluar 3 condiciones con un operador ternario?

Tags: php, yii, operador-ternario

¿Es posible evaluar más de 3 condiciones en un operador ternario? Estoy utilizando `yii 1.1` y para agregar color a una celda uso la siguiente condición...

```
'cssClassExpression'=> '$data->PRIORITY == 1 ? "red" : $data->PRIORITY==2 ? "yellow": "white"',
```

... pero no me funciona ya que si la prioridad es uno (*1*) siempre lo imprime con `yellow`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Independientemente de Yii, el cual no uso, en vez de usar un ternario múltiple, yo reflejaría la lógica que quieres implementar mediante **un objeto**. Esto aporta flexibilidad a tu aplicación, haciéndola más portable y más fácil de mantener/actualizar.

¿Qué va a pasar con tu ternario de tres condiciones si mañana hay que lidiar con 5 o con 50 códigos de colores? Si tienes un objeto, sólo tienes que agregar los elementos a ese objeto y el código que hace las comparaciones no tiene que ser modificado.

Piensa en un contexto en el que tu ternario es usado en varias decenas de archivos, habrá que ir a buscar ese código para adaptarlo a la nueva condición. Con un objeto, que estaría centralizado en un solo lugar, sólo modificas el objeto y listo. Además, trabajar con objetos permite que el código se integre con mayor facilidad a un modelo de datos: tabla de una base de datos, json, xml, etc.

En este ejemplo, trabajaríamos con colores fijos:

```
#Toda la lógica de colores de la App se refleja aquí
$colorCodes=(object) array('colors'=>array(1=>'red', 2=>'yellow', 3=>'white'));
```

Ahora en varios contextos:

```
#En el archivo número 1 de tu app:
#$data tiene este valor:
$data = (object) array('PRIORITY'=>1,'cssClassExpression'=>'');

#Prueba
$data->cssClassExpression=$colorCodes->colors{$data->PRIORITY};
var_dump($data);
```

**Salida:**

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["PRIORITY"]=>
  int(1)
  ["cssClassExpression"]=>
  string(3) "red"
}
```

Veamos otra prueba en otro contexto:

```
#En el archivo número 9,999.999 de tu app:
#$data tiene este valor:
$data = (object) array('PRIORITY'=>2,'cssClassExpression'=>'');

#Prueba
$data->cssClassExpression=$colorCodes->colors{$data->PRIORITY};
var_dump($data);
```

**Salida:**

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["PRIORITY"]=>
  int(1)
  ["cssClassExpression"]=>
  string(3) "yellow"
}
```

### Un momento crucial, la App debe evolucionar

Un día te dan la noticia de que hay que incorporar un nuevo código de color (`green`) y ya tienes `9,999,999` archivos donde has usado tu bonito ternario de tres opciones. Ese código tan bonito es ahora una pesadilla para ti, porque tendrás que ir en busca de esos `9,999,999` lugares donde lo has implementado para agregar ahora el color `green` y ¿crear un ternario de 4 condiciones?.

Pero no, ¡me has hecho caso! :) y **has reflejado la lógica en el objeto `$colorCodes`**. En ese momento darás gracias por esta respuesta, porque para adaptar el contexto de tu App a la nueva situación, sólo tendrás que escribir ¡10 carácteres! nuevos en la App, agregando esto al objeto `4=>'green'`. Nada más. El código seguirá funcionando bien, tanto si lo tienes en un archivo, como si lo tienes en miles de archivos.

El objeto **evolucionado** es este:

```
$colorCodes=(object) array('colors'=>array(1=>'red', 2=>'yellow', 3=>'white', 4=>'green'));
```

En la App habrá `$data`s  con `PRIORITY 4` a partir de ahora.

No hay pánico. Tu código es portable y no hay ningún problema:

```
#Estamos en el archivo número 1,000,000,000 de tu App
#Este es exactamente EL MISMO CÓDIGO del archivo 1 :-)
$data->cssClassExpression=$colorCodes->colors{$data->PRIORITY};
var_dump($data);
```

**Salida:**

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["PRIORITY"]=>
  int(4)
  ["cssClassExpression"]=>
  string(5) "green"
}
```

En un minuto el código fue adaptado a la nueva situación, simplemente modificando el objeto  `$colorCodes`.

## Nota

> Aquí te puse en ejemplo basado en datos fijos. Cabe decir que puedes
>   implementar con suma facilidad una opción basada en `default`, por
>   ejemplo en el caso de que `white` deba ser el color cuando no haya
>   códigos de color existentes en el objeto.

Answer (score 2):

Yo no uso yii... pero en C#, cuando quieres usar varias condiciones en un operador tenario, se deben de encerrar entre paréntesis.

Así:

```
 a ? b : (c ? d : e)
```

Entonces te quedaría algo como esto:

```
'cssClassExpression'=>  '$data->PRIORITY == 1 ? "red" : ($data->PRIORITY==2 ? "yellow": "white"'),
```

Answer (score 1):

**El operador ternario se evalúa de izquierda a derecha**. Entonces, si no agrupa las expresiones correctamente, obtendrá un resultado inesperado.

Como le ha sugerido [@A.Cedano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/29967/a-cedano) es una forma más correcta de hacerlo, pero si realmente desea usar un operador ternario, debe usar paréntesis para separarlos algo como esto:

```
$a = 2;
echo 
  ($a == 1 ? 'Uno'   :
  ($a == 2 ? 'Dos'   :
  ($a == 3 ? 'Tres' :
  ($a == 4 ? 'Cuatro'  : 
     'Otros'))));
// Imprime 'Dos'
exit;
```

[El consejo de PHP es [docs] :](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), dice en el **Ejemplo #4 Comportamiento Ternario poco obvio**

> Se recomienda que evite "apilar" expresiones ternarias. El
>   comportamiento de PHP cuando se usa más de un operador ternario dentro
>   de una sola declaración no es obvio.

Answer (score 1):

Como recomendación , para facilitar la lectura del código te recomendaría , no hacer operadores ternarios muy complejos , ni expresiones lambdas muy complejas....

Pero respecto a tu pregunta ¿Ya has probado con los paréntesis y los operadores lógicos "and" "or" si funciona?

Aquí hay dos cosas que no se que quieres hacer:

Si lo que si quieres hacer es esto:

Si(a==1 y a==2) {codigo }else{ codigo }

Prueba con esto:

```
'cssClassExpression'=> (CONDICION 1 && CONDICION 2)?RESULTADO TRUE:RESULTADO FALSE
```

Si lo que si quieres es concatenar `if` como  es esto:

Si(a==1) { if( a==2) {codigo} }else{ codigo }

Prueba a meter operadores ternarios dentro de paréntesis de forma jerárquica

```
'cssClassExpression'=>(CONDICION 1?RESULTADO TRUE:(CONDICION 2?RESULTADO TRUE:RESULTADO FALSE) ) ? RESULTADO TRUE:RESULTADO FALSE
```

O también puedes hacer esto:

```
'cssClassExpression'=>(CONDICION 1?RESULTADO TRUE:RESULTADO FALSE)  && (CONDICION 2?RESULTADO TRUE:RESULTADO FALSE) ? RESULTADO TRUE:RESULTADO FALSE
```

Todo dependerá del tipo de condicón que quieras hacer

piensa lo siguiente.... un operador ternario funciona de la siguiente forma

```
CONDICION ?RESULTADO TRUE:RESULTADO FALSE
```

si en el apartado "CONDICION" se evalúa true , se ejecuta "RESULTADO TRUE " , Si "CONDICION1" se evalúa false se ejecuta "RESULTADO FALSE"