# @extends con conficionales IF Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Tengo una pagina con 4 tipos de usuarios diferentes, Admin, SubAdmin, Medico y Paciente.

Desde mi controlador, al cargar la vista le envio una variable llamada Role, esta indica bueno, el Rol de mi usuario.
Lo que quiero, es que, dependiendo de el tipo de rol me `extienda` un layout diferente.

Tengo 4 layouts de Menu diferente, lo que quiero, es que dependiendo el usuario, me cargue su Menu correspondiente.

Intente con un

```
@if($Role == "Admin")
   @extends('layout.template_Admin') 
@else 
  @if($Role == "Medico")
```

y asi, sucesivamente con cada layout, el problema es que cuando cargan el menu no aparece, o si aparece el boton para desplegarlo no funciona, es como si cada que le doy click evaluara el `if` y se cargara el layout de nuevo, pero no abre nada.

Asi que intenté

```
@extends($Role="Administrador" ? 'layouts.template_Admin' : $Role = "Medico" ? "layouts.template_Medico" : 'layouts.template_Admin')
```

Pero el problema es que aunque la variable esta cargada como 'Medico', lo ignora y carga el template del `Administrador`. no se cual es el problema.

---

Comment: Igual antes de seguir con eso te sugiero darle ina mirada a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/326033/c%C3%B3mo-evaluar-3-condiciones-con-un-operador-ternario)

Comment: Gracias bro, voy a ver el enlace. De todas formas ya resolvi el problema, aunque de manera diferente.

Answer (score 2):

Bien, no encontre la solucion al problema de los `@extends`, pero resolvi mi problema de otra manera.

Como dije, tenia un template, y basicamente mi 'error' por asi decirlo, fue querer cargar 'templates' diferentes para cada usuario, cuando en realidad lo unico que necesitaba era cargar "Menus" diferentes, asi que en lugar de cargar todo un template diferente dependiendo el usuario, lo que hice fue lo siguiente.

En el template original, la base por decirlo, lo que hice fue crear un `@if` que dependiendo de la variable "Role" hara un "Include" de una menu diferente.

Luego, desde mis paginas (Las que tienen el contenido, formularios, tablas, graficas, etc. ) desde esa pagina, extendere el template base, y este ya tendra incluido el menu que le corresponde.

```
 @if ($Role == "Administrador")
            @include('components.Menu_Admin')
        @elseif ($Role == "Medico")
            @include('components.Menu_Medico')
        @endif
```

Ojo, esto esta dentro de mi template, es como un `componente` llamado Menu que estoy incluyendo dentro de mi template, el cual luego llamare desde mi pagina principal.

Espero les sirva